# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: ContactEntity is not mapped [select c from ContactEntity c]

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, hibernate-tools

I am new to hibernate and trying to configure the **JPA console** in an eclipse to have some research on JPAQL. I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=50Hx3N_a9as and setup the `JPA console` by downloading `JBoss Hibernate tool` successfully.

Note: I am using `Oracle DB`. In Database I've many schemas, out of those I want to use `Admin schema`.

But when I tried to execute simple JPQL I see below error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: ContactEntity is not mapped [select c from ContactEntity c]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1907)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.Util.invokeMethod(Util.java:43)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.AbstractSessionFacade.createQuery(AbstractSessionFacade.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.HQLQueryPage.setSession(HQLQueryPage.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.HibernateExtension$2.execute(HibernateExtension.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.HibernateExtension.execute(HibernateExtension.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.HibernateExtension.executeHQLQuery(HibernateExtension.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.executeHQLQuery(ConsoleConfiguration.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.hqleditor.HQLEditor.executeQuery(HQLEditor.java:447)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.actions.ExecuteQueryAction.execute(ExecuteQueryAction.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.actions.ExecuteQueryAction.run(ExecuteQueryAction.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.actions.ExecuteQueryAction.runWithEvent(ExecuteQueryAction.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$6.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: ContactEntity is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3704)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3593)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:718)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:574)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190)
    ... 53 more
```

I tried to apply many links from github but none of them worked for me. Any pointers?

[image]

**persistance.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
        <persistence-unit name="conn" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
               <class>com.XXX.XXX.ContactEntity</class>
                <class>com.XXX.XXX.StudentEntity</class>
                <class>com.XXX.XXX.AddressEntity</class>
            <properties>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:test"/>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test"/>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="test"/>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

[image]

```
@Entity
@Table(name = ADM_CONTACT")
public class ContactEntity implements Serializable {
    ............
}
```

Comment: where is your persistence.xml file and what is in it?

Comment: So why haven't you put this "ContactEntity" into the persistence.xml in a `<class>` tag?

Comment: Show your ContactEntity class and mapping. Is it annotated with @Entity or mapped in xml?

Comment: Yes, My Entity `@Entity
@Table(name = ADM_CONTACT")
public class ContactEntity implements Serializable {`

Comment: The query you're executing is a JPQL query, but your configuration might be of HQL, that might be your problem?

Comment: I think you are missing some configuration letting eclipse know how your mapping is defined..